# tk button changes appearance

Tags: python-2.7, button, tkinter

So I was doing this program and noticed that both my buttons look initially like this 
[image]

And after I run my program for some time the second button changes it appearance to this 
[image]

When does this happen?

Here's my code :/ in case I am doing something that should not be done. I am doing this in python 2.7.8 in IDLE.

```
import time
import  Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import StringVar
import threading
global root
root = tk.Tk()
x = tk.StringVar()
x.set('false')

def xval(*args):
    try:
        for i in range(0,9):
            global x
            print x.get()
            if x.get()== 'false' :
                print "x=false %d time"%i
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print "waiting"
            root.update()
    except:
        pass

def stop(event):
                resume_btn.configure(state="normal")
                global x
                x.set('true')
                print "execution stopped:%s"%x


def start(event):
                global x
                x.set('false')
                print "execution started:%s"%x
                xval()


root.title("GUI-Data Retrieval")
th = threading.Event()
t = threading.Thread(target=xval,args=(th,))
t.deamon=True
t.start()
x_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Stop", background="Snow", width=20, relief="raised")
x_btn.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="W", padx=20, pady=5)
x_btn.bind('<Button-1>',stop)
resume_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Start", background="Snow", width=20, relief="raised")
resume_btn.configure(state="disabled")
resume_btn.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky="W", padx=20, pady=5)
resume_btn.bind('<Button-1>',start)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For the benefit of others, the problem can be reproduced by clicking `Start` and then `Stop`.  As for the fix, ...

Comment: Why are you using `bind` on the button rather than using the `command` attribute? That's the root of the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley ohh..... finally thanks a ton for this help... i was going nuts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your binding is handled before the default bindings. It is the default bindings that change the appearance of the button when it is clicked on. You are disabling the button on a click, preventing the default behavior from resetting the appearance of the button when you release the mouse button.

Unless there's a specific reason to do otherwise, you should use the `command` attribute of the button widget rather than try to create your own bindings.